# Saving content of aiohttp response on s3

Tags: amazon-s3, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I want to download a page and put it on S3. I use `aiohttp` to download a page and save it to a file:

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        while True:
            chunk = await response.content.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
            if not chunk:
                break
            file.write(chunk)
```

What is the best way to save it on S3 without loading content into memory?

I am using [aiobotocore](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiobotocore). `response.content` can't be provided as an argument for `s3.put_object`. And aiobotocore client doesn't have `upload_fileobj` method.

Comment: I suggest making an issue on aiobotocore for supporting `aiohttp.StreamReader` as payload.